# iOS Barcode scanning where there is an indicator for possible bar code

Tags: avfoundation, barcode-scanner

The bar code scanners in some of the iOS apps identify the object under inspection and indicate it in various ways. How can this be done, are there any specific libraries that can be used for this.

To be more precise, here is the scanner in Amazon app (I have seen this in some other places too). How is this happening (the stars sprinkling), is there some open source library that is being used.

[image]